# React: Why sign up form is not creating new user in firebase users?

Tags: reactjs

Here I'm trying to build a signup form using the react-hook form. I'm trying to build a restaurant website for my own purpose. But I have tried many times. But I'm getting many errors. First of all when I sign up a new user then firebase is not creating a new user. The form is not validating completely. But I can't find out the problem. Where is the problem? Can anyone help, please?

Here is my signUp.js file

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { useAuth } from './useAuth'
    import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
    import logo from '../../Images/logo2.png';
    import './SignUp.css'
    
    const SignUp = () => {
    
        const [returningUser, setReturningUser] = useState(false);
        const {register, handleSubmit, watch, errors} = useForm();
        
        const auth = useAuth();
    
        const onSubmit = data => {
            if(returningUser){
                if(data.email && data.password){
                auth.signIn(data.email, data.password)
                }
            }
            else{
                if(data.name && data.email && data.password){
                    auth.signUp(data.email, data.password, data.name)
                }
            }
        }
    
    
    
        return (
            <div className="sign-up">
                <div className="container">
    
                <div className="logo-container ">
                    <img src={logo} alt=""/>
    
                </div>
                {
                    returningUser ?
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit) } action="" className="py-5">
                        
                        {
                           auth && auth.user != null && <p className="text-danger">{auth.user.error}</p>
                        }
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input  name="email" className="form-control" {...register('email', {requried: true})} placeholder="Email"/>
                            {errors && errors.email && <span className="error">Email is Required</span>}
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="password" className="form-control" {...register('password', {requried: true})} placeholder="password"/>
                            {errors&& errors.password && <span className="error">Password is Required</span>}
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <button className="btn btn-danger">Sign In</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="option text-center">
                            <label  onClick={() => setReturningUser(false)}>Create a new Account</label>
                        </div>
    
    
    
                    </form>
                    :
                    <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="name" className="form-control" 
                           
                           {...register('name', {requried: true})} placeholder="Name"/>
                            {errors && errors.name && <span className="error">Name is Required</span>}
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" className="form-control" {...register('email', {required: true})} placeholder="Email"/>
                            {errors && errors.email && <span className="error">Email is required</span>}
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="password" className="form-control" {...register('password', {requried: true})} placeholder="Password"/>
                            {errors && errors.password && <span className="error">Password is Required</span>}
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                        <button className="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    
    
                        </div>
                        <div className="option text-center">
                            <label onClick={() => setReturningUser(true)}>Already have an account!</label>
                        </div>
    
    
                    </form>
                }
    
                </div>
            
                
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default SignUp;
```

**Here is my useAuth.js file**

```
// import { faWindowRestore } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import firebaseConfig from "../../firebase.config";
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router";

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  const auth = Auth();

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={auth}>{props.children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const useAuth = () => {
  useContext(AuthContext);
};
export const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  let auth = useAuth();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        auth.user ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

const Auth = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
        const currentUser = user;
        setUser(currentUser);
        // ...
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        // ...
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const signIn = (email, password) => {
    return firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((res) => {
        // Signed in
        setUser(res.user);
        window.history.back();
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
      });
  };

  const signUp = (email, password, name) => {
    return firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((res) => {
        // firebase
        //   .auth()
        //   .currentUser.updateProfile({
        //     displayName: name,
        //   })
        //   .then(() => {
            setUser(res.user);
            window.history.back();
          })
        // Signed in

        // ...
      
      .catch((error) => {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // ..
      });
  };
  const signOut = () => {
    return firebase
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then((res) => {
        // Sign-out successful.
        setUser(null);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // An error happened.
      });
  };
  return {
    user,
    signIn,
    signUp,
    signOut,
  };
};

export default Auth;
```

Comment: @Surjeet Bhadauriya

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details describing the problem. Try to answer questions such as: What exactly is wrong with the validation? What's the expected outcome and what's the actual outcome? This will help other users understand your problem and suggest a solution.

Comment: Solved this problem.But I'm getting error in another place. Here is the link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67256404/unhandled-rejection-typeerror-cannot-read-property-signup-of-undefined